# Pass Authenticate Header and query Parameter in Retrofit Request

Tags: android, retrofit

http://localhost:503/api/services/app/User/GetUserForEdit?Id=3
This is the Api which return me user detail.
I get the User_id and access_token when i login the application.Now i need to pass the access_token in the request header and pass the User_id using query parameter.How i passed these two things in my request.I am using retrofit.

Comment: share your retrofit request code.

Answer (score 1):

```
@GET(URL)
Call<Response> funcName(@Header("access_token") String token, @Field("user_id") String id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
@GET("user/edit")
Call<User> getUser(@Header("Authorization") String authorization, @Field("user_id") int userId, @Field("username") String username);
```